# Shiny leafpop::addPopupGraphs bug, looking for a walkaround

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I experienced a strange behavior of the `leafpop` function `addPopupGraphs`. This is a reproducible example illustrating the problem.

After the execution, if you click on a marker, a popup-graph appears. If you just move the slide-bar and click again on the marker no popup appears, I want to make it appear.

I saw that if I just comment the row `label = my.var`, the popups work fine, but I need the dependency from variable my.var.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leafpop)
library(ggplot2)

ui = fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "potatoes",
              label = "Potatoes:",
              min = 1,
              max = 10,
              value = 2,
              step = 1,
              animate = F,
              width = '100%'),
  leafletOutput('my_map', height = 700)
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$my_map <- renderLeaflet({

    my_map <- function(my.var = character()){

      my.plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_line()

      m <- leaflet() %>%
        addTiles(urlTemplate = 'https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png') %>%
        setView(lng = 10,
                lat = 49,
                zoom = 4) %>%
        addCircleMarkers(lng = c(10, 10),
                         lat = c(49, 50),
                         group = 'A',
                         label = my.var
                         ) %>%
        addPopupGraphs(list(my.plot,my.plot),
                       group = 'A',
                       width = 500, height = 300)

      return(m)
    }

    my_map(input$potatoes)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/r-spatial/leafpop/issues/12#issuecomment-652549650 for a solution. You need to change the `group` argument with your input, then it will render properly.

Comment: I'm curious how you would do that in this case. Group doesn't have the input in it, so.... how would you implement that here?

Comment: The case in the leafpop issues above is this case...

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you could use `mapview::popupGraph()` instead. It works for me! More info [here](https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/articles/articles/mapview_04-popups.html).

I just passed `popup = mapview::popupGraph(...)` to your marker function.
Something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leafpop)
library(ggplot2)

ui = fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "potatoes",
              label = "Potatoes:",
              min = 1,
              max = 10,
              value = 2,
              step = 1,
              animate = F,
              width = '100%'),
  leafletOutput('my_map', height = 700)
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$my_map <- renderLeaflet({

    my_map <- function(my.var = character()){

      my.plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_line()

      m <- leaflet() %>%
        addTiles(urlTemplate = 'https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png') %>%
        setView(lng = 10,
                lat = 49,
                zoom = 4) %>%
        addCircleMarkers(lng = c(10, 10),
                         lat = c(49, 50),
                         group = 'A',
                         label = my.var,
      ## Replaced leafpop::addPopuppGraph() here
                         popup = mapview::popupGraph(list(my.plot,my.plot))
                         )

      return(m)
    }

    my_map(input$potatoes)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'm sure the guys at [leafpop](https://github.com/r-spatial/leafpop) would love a bug report ;).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution @AF7. I tried both solutions from @TimSalabim and you. Both works, although yours was better because of less complication.
I found that the mapview::popupGraph doesn't exist anymore in mapview package (It is Dec31,2022). It only exists in leafpop::popupGraph.

Inspired from your code to use mapview and a page here: https://environmentalinformatics-marburg.github.io/mapview/popups/html/popups.html

I wrote the popup with mapview instead of leaflet:

```
mapview(myMapObject, popup = leafpop::popupGraph(Graphs,width=200,height=200))@map
```

which worked in shiny with no problem.

Graphs were the list of Graphs which the number of those should match the number (and order) of the myMapObject.
The myMapObject can be a point layer or a polygon.

my case, I had a polygon object and I had calculated the graphs for it,